# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/build/web/index.html' in Flutter with Firebase Functions

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, enoent

Pretty much as the title says.

[image: This is the error I am getting in the firebase functions logs]

But the file is definitely there:

[image]

So I am stumped :(

I'm following this: https://almog.io/blog/dynamic-open-graph-meta-tags-flutter-web to set up dynamic open graph meta tags, the function as below:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const fs = require("fs");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const BotDetector = require("device-detector-js/dist/parsers/bot");
const DEBUG_BOT = false;
admin.initializeApp();

// Main firebase function called on firebase.json rewrites rules
exports.dynamicMetaTagsUpdate = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  // console.log("dynamicMetaTagsUpdate Called");

  let html = fs.readFileSync("build/web/index.html", "utf8");
  const {id} = request.query;
  const botDetector = new BotDetector();
  const userAgent = request.headers["user-agent"].toString();
  const bot = botDetector.parse(userAgent);
  const url = "https://voiceofrenewables.com/post/"+ id;

  // If bot get chat data from Firebase database
  if (bot || DEBUG_BOT) {
    try {
      // console.log("running try");
      const ref = admin.database().ref("Posts");
      const chartData = ref.child(id).get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const object = {title: snapshot.child("title").val(), description: snapshot.child("title").val(), imageUrl: snapshot.child("imageUrl").val()};
          return object;
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

      const htmlData = await chartData;
      // HTML to return with updated open graph meta tags
      html = `
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <title>"The Voice of Renewables"</title>
                <meta name="description" content="${htmlData.description}">
                <meta name="title" content="${htmlData.title}">
                <meta property="og:title" content="${htmlData.title}" />
                <meta property="og:description" content="${htmlData.description}" />
                <meta property="og:image" content="${htmlData.imageUrl}" />
                <meta property="og:image:secure" content="${htmlData.imageUrl}" />
                <meta property="og:url" content="${url}" />
           
              </head>
            <body>
             <h1>The Voice of Renewables</h1>
              <h2>${htmlData.title}</h2>
              <p>${htmlData.description}</p>
              <img src="${htmlData.imageUrl}" />
            </body>
            </html>
            `;
      return response.send(html);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return response.send(html);
    }
  }
  return response.send(html);
});
```

and then in firebase.json

```
 "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "post/**",
        "function": "dynamicMetaTagsUpdate"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

I have tried using both the index.html from the build/web folder and the web folder itself, neither are working, neither using relative or absolute route. I'm utterly stuck now. Please help :)